# "Breaking" into Samsung phone

Tags: samsung, security, lock-screens

One of my colleagues has recently passed away and I am left with a task to retrieve data (especially pictures) from his phone - Samsung Galaxy A3 (2017).

Unfortunately, he set a numerical code to lock the screen and I was unable to get through it with any conventional methods I found online - all require access to the Samsung account, or Google account, or some other prerequisites, that are not fulfilled in this case.

Does anybody have any trick to get past the security?

Comment: If your company/organization has the budget, ask them to hire a professional who is skilled enough to develop and execute an exploit on an Android device. As I see it your best bet is to exploit the vulnerabilities in the device to gain access. One promising vulnerability is in bluetooth. See https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-fixes-no-user-interaction-bug-in-androids-bluetooth-component/

Answer (score 0):

If you have his phone number, could this work for you:

1. Call the phone
2. Accept the call and press the back button without disconnecting
3. Now you should have access to the device completely.

Comment: This does not work on latest Androids. I don't know about older versions.

Comment: Yeah idk I just found the solution on Google xd